# JSefa using CsvSubRecordList on single row CSV data

Tags: java, csv

I'm running into an issue with JSefa when I attempt to parse a CSV record in sub lists.

Given the following CSV data String (assume their is a header line at the first line, not shown here)

`REC,data1,INF,data2,data3,LOL,data4,LOL,data5,LOL,data6`

I'm trying to deserialize it into the `Record` class with the following model classes

```
@CsvDataType(defaultPrefix = "REC")
class Record {
   @CsvField(pos = 0)
   int data;

   @CsvSubRecordList(pos = 1, records = @Record(prefix = "INF"))
   List<Informative> informativeData;

   @CsvSubRecordList(pos = 2, records = @Record(prefix = "LOL"))
   List<LaughingOutLoud> funnyData;
}

@CsvDataType(defaultPrefix = "INF")
class Informative {
  @CsvField(pos = 0) 
  int data;

  @CsvField(pos = 1)
  int moreData;
}

@CsvDataType(defaultPrefix = "LOL)
class LaughingOutLoud {
   @CsvField(pos = 0)
   int data;
}
```

and the following `CsvConfiguration`

```
csvConfiguration = new CsvConfiguration();
csvConfiguration.setFieldDelimiter(',');
int headerLine = 1;
boolean hasFooter = false;
boolean storeFailedLines = false;
csvConfiguration.setLineFilter(new HeaderAndFooterFilter(headerLine, hasFooter, storeFailedLines));
```

The `Record` class is created, with `data` properly filled, however the two `List` fields are `null`.

However, if I attempt to parse the following CSV String data, putting line breaks between the sub lists,

Again, assume their is a header line at the first line, not shown here.
`REC,data1\r\nINF,data2,data3\r\nLOL,data4\r\nLOL,data5\r\nLOL,data6`

it'll parse the sub records and create the `List`s correctly.

How can I get it parse without having to put linebreaks in between the sub records? I don't see any property in the `CsvConfiguration` class that would correct this.

Comment: is this line right? `@CsvDataType(defaultPrefix = "LOL)`

Comment: it's missing a closing double quote